# Implement Camera on Android Emulator | Need some knowledge

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, qemu

I'm interested in doing some enhancements to android emulator (implement webcam on emulator). Therefore I'm following the android source and emulators source to get basic understanding  & the connection between modules. But its really hard to understand it for someone who is new to android. Therefore can anyone please direct me to some resource to understand this. May be some proper documentation, tutorials or anything that i can understand this.

And since i'm interested in emulator if i change the code of emulator with in "external\qemu" , then build it using "m emulator" and run using "emulator" , will those changes effect or apply onto the started emulator.

And if anyone know please let me know that, what is the sdk it uses when it run as "emulator" from the build android source code. Cos if i want to install some application to that emulator how can i do that?

Please help if anyone know...

Answer (score 0):

You will want to implement a compatible camera interface in QEMU. QEMU is a multi-platform system emulator which provides a complete emulated system.

I would suggest implementing a camera which matches an existing hardware device. For this, you will likely need to study the existing drivers which are part of the kernel source.

Comment: I know it is an old question, but its still interesting. Now camera emulation is integrted in Android emulator. What about QEMU? What was the design of camera emulation? And similar questions... Do you kno anything about that?